# How to change icon path dynamically on folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, path

I want to keep my icons structure when I move my system, when I click on browse it gives me a really long path.

When I change systems or reformat, I need to do this all over again...

Some scripts I've written used this type of path:

{curdir}/portable-apps.ico

Is there a way to insert a variable in the browse path for Windows?

Path is this:

```
 I:\++++++++Data_2016-nov2017\portable_apps\ico\portable-apps.ico
```

I would like the path to be something like this:

```
 {curdir}\portable-apps.ico
```

So the portable-apps.ico gets used from root directory?

[image]

Comment: which script are you using? they can use [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) as always, and if you mean the shortcut then it's a duplicate of [Using relative paths for Windows shortcuts](https://superuser.com/q/644407/241386)

Comment: Not using any script, I want to add the proper path as a shortcut, the problem is my directory structure and drive letters change per system configurations. These are portable apps. Can you tell me what to put in there for this type of path? : I:\++++++++Data_2016-nov2017\portable_apps\ico\portable-apps.ico  to for example have it be possible to be changed to Z:\portable_apps\ico\portable-apps.ico

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using relative paths for Windows shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/644407/using-relative-paths-for-windows-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

The icon dialogue can use environment variables, as shown in the default dialogue which references %SystemRoot%.

You could save the path as a reference to an environment variable, and then make sure that variable is set during log on using a script.

[image]

[Lifehacker](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZYEJclx3AiAJ:https://lifehacker.com/259018/create-your-own-environment-variables-for-quick-folder-navigation%20&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au) gave the following description for setting your own variable names:

1. Right-click the "My Computer" icon (Computer in Vista)
2. Choose "Properties" from the context menu
3. Click the "Advanced" tab ("Advanced system settings" link in Vista)
4. Click the "Environment Variables" button
5. Under the "User variables" section, click new
6. Enter the hotstring in the "Variable name" field and the path in the "Variable value" field
7. Click OK
   Once you've created the environment variable, enclosing it in percent signs (e.g., %music%) in the Run box, Explorer location, or lots of other similar locations will jump straight to the full path. This is a really handy tip, especially if you're interested in navigating your file system with keywords.

Comment: The paths used in the question make me think that the value for the variable isn't available at login, only once the media is inserted.

Comment: There are no options like this in windows 10...