# Bulk-convert shortcuts to relative shortcuts in Windows

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

I've been using the utility [Relative](https://superuser.com/a/644421/284911) to create my relative shortcuts a bit faster since I know it. The problem is my drive is plenty of old shortcuts I would like to convert without re-making them one by one. Is there any utility allowing for this? If there's a solution that requires me to select them one by one will be fine. This will also solve the problem with Windows that sometimes destroys the once programmed path in normal shortcuts, before asking you to look for mistakes in the path...

Comment: Are they folder shortcuts? What does the target path look like -- `"d:\backup"` or `"explorer.exe D:\backup"`?

Comment: @w32sh the ones created by Windows, just ``"D:\whatever"``, but the relative ones are ``%windir%\explorer.exe ..\..\..\"whatever"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a quick VBScript to bulk change shortcut targets. It invokes `Relative.exe` and overwrites the existing shortcuts, changing the target to relative paths.

**Note:** Before proceeding, please back up your original shortcuts. Always test with sample files first.

*(Please update the Relative.exe path in Line#9 of the script if the program is installed on a different location.)*

```
Option Explicit
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0  Then WScript.Quit
Dim WshShell, WshShortcut, sAppPath, oFSO, sCmd
Dim sSrcFile, sTarget, sArgs, sWStyle, sHotkey, sSkipped, i
Set WshShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO =  CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sSkipped = "List of shortcuts skipped:" & vbCrLf  & vbCrLf

sAppPath = """" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Relative\Relative.exe" & """"

For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count - 1 
   sSrcFile = WScript.Arguments(i)   
   If LCase(Right(sSrcFile, 4)) <> ".lnk" Then Exit For
   
   'Get shortcut properties
   Set WshShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(sSrcFile)
   sTarget = WshShortcut.TargetPath
   sWStyle = WshShortcut.WindowStyle
   sArgs = WshShortcut.Arguments
   sHotkey = WshShortcut.Hotkey
   
   'Skip if target has the .exe suffix, or the target is a File
   If InStr(sTarget, ".exe") > 0 Or oFSO.FileExists (sTarget) Then
      sTarget = ""
   End If

   'Skip if target is already in relative path format
   If InStr(sTarget, ".\") = 0 And Trim(sTarget) <> "" Then
      'Run Relative.exe and overwrite existing shortcut
      sCmd = sAppPath & " " & sTarget & " " & """" & _
        Replace(sSrcFile, ".lnk", "") & """"
      WshShell.Run sCmd,1, 1    
      
      'Restore shortcut Hotkey and Window style setting
      WScript.Sleep 500
      Set WshShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(sSrcFile)
      WshShortcut.WindowStyle = sWStyle
      If sHotkey <> "" Then WshShortcut.Hotkey = sHotkey
      WshShortcut.Save
   Else
      sSkipped = sSkipped & sSrcFile & vbCrLf
   End If
   
Next

If Len (sSkipped) > 32 Then WScript.Echo sSkipped
```

**Instructions**

1. Copy the above code to Notepad and save it as `ToRelative.vbs`.
2. Open your `Sendto` folder (Hint: run `shell:sendto` in Start/Run.)
3. Place the script's shortcut in the SendTo folder.
4. Right-click a set of .lnk files, click Send To, and select
   `ToRelative` in the Send to menu.