# How do you set the target and not the target path of a .lnk file programmatically with powershell or c++?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, c++, c#

How do you set the target and NOT the targetPath of a .lnk file
?
I can't find any .dll I can use in powershell or c#.
Most people might try and tell to use wshshell to set the .targetpath of the .lnk variable.
That's not the question that I am asking.

[A bit of help from this question as a resource](https://superuser.com/questions/644407/using-relative-paths-for-windows-shortcuts)

It would be nice to set the target with environmental variables using powershell...
But I can't find anything...Most people keep talking about wshshell, but if you try and use that you'll notice that it doesn't really use environmental variables as a path setting target. In fact forcing it just causes errors saying targetpath is out of range.

[Some more resources I found useful and added](http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/wshom.aspx#google_vignette)

Comment: Your words don't match how a shell link (.lnk) file works.  If you are able to write code in c++, then see [this](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-SHLLINK/%5bMS-SHLLINK%5d.pdf) specification for the file format and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinka) for the COM interface you will use to manipulate the lnk itself.  There are also c# wrappers if using COM is not something you already know how to do.

Comment: You searches have probably not been fruitful because your were searching for lnk or shortcut and not [shell link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/links).  Also.. as people have told you already, the windows scripting host can do almost anything you want with the shell links.

Comment: Ok thanks. I found some resources to help learn more about that... [Useful Site](http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/wshom.aspx#google_vignette)...
I'll take some time and go over a few books before I'll post an answer. 
Any help with the c# wrappers in powershell would be great tho...

Comment: thanks... actually after having gone through some c++ docs Ive started working on a c++ implementation for code... if I get down to it... I'll post it. However this example is too simple and already completed for this procedure... 
I went over the link item with powershell using get-item, and reviewed it using format-hex *..... Now I'll try and modify the binary data finding the flags?

Comment: I've been composing an answer with PowerShell snippets. I'll be home in a few hours and post what I've got. Just been busy and legally blind requires high zoom and slows me down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after having gone over some of the docs and procedures for working the wshshell object I have actually come up with a solution that works and that I'll probably employ... at work.
It took me a while to realize that I can not actually set the targetpath for an
executable using /runas with the Target Location in Sys32s Powershell Folder...
Instead... I'll just set the working directory to System32, and the TargetPath to runAs.exe...
From the arguments you provide to runAs.exe it is that you provide your extended powershell .ps1 launch arguments.

Here is a sample which launches my gradient app after prompting for your microsoft password....--->

```
    $myAppName = 'spectrumFormLauncher.ps1'
    $myLinkName = 'myLink.lnk'
    $myAppFolder = 'Spex'
    $myIconName = 'spex.ico'
    
    $cactName =  $env:userprofile +"\documents\"+$myAppFolder
    $cactName2 = $env:userprofile + "\desktop"
    
    $SourceExeArg = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    $SourceExe = "C:\Windows\System32\runAs.exe"
    $myDom = $env:USERDOMAIN
    $myU = $env:USERNAME
    $Arg = '/profile /user:'+$myDom+"\"+$myU       
    $myAppZoned = '"'+$cactName+'\modules\'+$myAppName+'"'
    $ArgumentsToParameters = ' "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle hidden -File ' + $myAppZoned
    $ArgumentsToSourceExe = $Arg + $ArgumentsToParameters
    $DestinationPath = $cactName2+"\" +$myLinkName
    $testShortCut = Test-Path $DestinationPath
    if($testShortCut -eq $true)
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $DestinationPath -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse
    }        
    $SourceExe2 ="C:\Windows\System32\"      
    $iconSpot = $cactName + "\media\"+$myIconName        
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($DestinationPath)
    $Shortcut.IconLocation = $iconSpot
    $Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $SourceExe2
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $SourceExe
    $Shortcut.Arguments = $ArgumentsToSourceExe
    $Shortcut.Save()
```

[Spex the Gradient App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ho2Z.gif)

Where I'm at in the c++ procedure

```
// TODO: Place code here.
//HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc)
// HRESULT ResolveIt(HWND hwnd, LPCSTR lpszLinkFile, LPWSTR lpszPath, int iPathBufferSize)
    const wchar_t *lpszPathObj = L"C:\\users\\zero8\\desktop\\go.lnk";
    const char *lpszpathLink = "powershell.exe"; 
    const wchar_t *lpszDesc = L"whatever";
    CreateLink(lpszPathObj, lpszpathLink, lpszDesc);
```

[image]

[image]